# How to process Collection of messages to topic using Kafka Streams

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a task to send bulk messages around 100k records to kafka topic efficiently.

Right now i'm using kafka template to achieve this

```
Map<GenericRecord, GenericRecord> allMessages;
allMessages.entrySet().stream().forEach(p -> {
            kafkaTemplateForAvro.send(sink, p.getKey(), p.getValue());
        });
```

to process 100000 records it's taking around 1.30 min
is there any other approach this in less time?

Comment: The code looks fine to me. Depending on how large the messages are, you could try tuning the kafka producer. A good place to start would be to change `batch.size` and `linger.ms`.

Comment: May I ask how you use the code in Kafka Streams? Looks a pure Kafka Producer code to me.

Comment: I didn't uses kafkastreams in my code. So I want to use Kafka streams here to send message in less time